# Swift 4 Using Generics as Return Value

Tags: swift, generics, decodable

I have a protocol like so:

```
protocol ModelProtocol{

    func parse<T.Model>(data: Data) -> Array<T>? {}

}
```

The return is an array of option values. The method takes in data, parses it and returns the array of parsed objects from API data.

The type of data that the API returns is called `MyData` that has an array as the value of the dictionary.

I parse the JSON like so

```
func parse<T>(data: Data) -> Array<T>? {
    do {

        let newJSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        let menu = try newJSONDecoder.decode(MyData.self, from:data)
        let dataArray = menu.data //array
        let modelArray = Array<T>()
        for object in dataArray {


            modelArray.append(object)

        }

        return modelArray

    }
    catch {
        print("error while parsing:\(error.localizedDescription)")
        return nil
    }

}
```

I get error on the line where I append into the array to be returned.

> Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(MyData.Drinks)'

Ultimately I want the returned array to have objects of the type that is in the array `MyData.data`- in this case, the type is `Drinks`. But more broadly, I want the method to return any type that is in any JSON payload. The goal is to create a method that can take in any data and return any object as parsed object of type X in the array.

How do I do this?

Comment: It's confusing that the variable `MyData` and the type `MyData` have the same name. Further the generic type **must** be constrained to `Decodable.`

Comment: OK, I can change the name of the variable, but the problem still holds.

Comment: You should update your question to include a [mcve]. Your protocol declaration is flawed, it doesn't even compile. Moreover, you should include the declaration of `MyData`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the code does not compile:

> Protocol methods must not have bodies

so you have to remove the braces:

```
protocol ModelProtocol{
    func parse<T : Decodable>(data: Data) -> Array<T>?
}
```

To solve your problem create `MyData` also as generic

```
struct MyData<T : Decodable> : Decodable {
    let data : [T]?
}
```

and declare `parse`

```
func parse<T : Decodable>(data: Data) -> Array<T>? {

    do {
        let newJSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
        let menu = try newJSONDecoder.decode(MyData<T>.self, from:data)
        return menu.data
    }
    catch {
        print("error while parsing: ", error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

`print` always the entire `error` to get detailed information about the decoding error. `localizedDescription` is too broad.

---

If `data` is expected to be non-optional make `parse` `throw` and hand over the decoding error

```
protocol ModelProtocol{
    func parse<T : Decodable>(data: Data) throws -> Array<T>
}

struct MyData<T : Decodable> : Decodable {
    let data : [T]
}

func parse<T : Decodable>(data: Data) throws -> Array<T> {
    let newJSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()
    let menu = try newJSONDecoder.decode(MyData<T>.self, from:data)
    return menu.data
}
```